# Switch back workspace movement to up/down instead of left/right on 22.04

Tags: 22.04, workspace-switcher

Any possibility to change the movement on the workspace switcher back to vertical instead of horizontal?
Guess it's just a matter of habit but I'm wondering if it's possible and how

Ubuntu LTS 22.04

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## This is a feature

This is a feature of the newest Gnome Shell used by Ubuntu 22.04. There is no built-in way to revert back to the vertical workspace.

## Use a Gnome Shell Extension

First you need to install the extension manager, as Firefox cannot do this anymore. Open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

Or you can open **Ubuntu Software** app and search for Extension Manager:

[image]

Once it is installed open the app and search for **Vertical Workspaces** within this app:

[image]

**Update:** The extension *Vertical Workspace* is now known as [V-Shell (Vertical Workspace)](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5177/vertical-workspaces/)

As you can see there are two Gnome Shell Extensions that claim to do the job. Select and install one of them and see if it meets your needs. If not, try the other one.

**Disclaimer:**

I have tried neither of these gnome shell extensions.

Hope this helps

Comment: "**Vertical Workspaces**" works for me; it's highly configurable. I prefer the workspace dock on the right (default: left). Thank you very much

Comment: Looks to me like this has either been removed or renamed

Comment: I have found an extension called `Workspace Switch Wraparound`, but I cannot find how to configure it.

Comment: @ioaniatr I looked at the extension, It seems serves a different purpose. If you have it installed and you have say four workspaces, you can use the scroll wheel of your mouse to cycle through them after you press the "Super" key. Without this extension you can go from 1 to 4 but not back to 1 by scrolling past 4. You will be stuck at 4. There is no user configuration.

Comment: It is now called [V-Shell (Vertical Workspaces)](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5177/vertical-workspaces/). Works like a charm, <kbd>Super+↓</kbd> shortcut work by default on 22.04.

Comment: Thanks @ponsfrilus I have added this information in the answer.

Comment: This extension now is called `Workspace Switcher Manager`. You need to go into `general settings`, and enable `Reverse Workspace Orientation` . It offers more options as well, as size, colors etc.

Comment: @ioaniatr `V-Shell` is still available. Feel free to write another answer recommending `Workspace Switcher manager`. Both extensions are from the same author.

Comment: @user68186 `Workspace Switcher Manager` works, and sets desktops vertically. However, it somehow disables my navigation shortcuts from custom keyboard shortcuts. Does this extension control the shortcuts?

Comment: @ioaniatr As I say in the answer, I have not tried these extensions. So, I cannot say if this extension control shortcuts or not. Please contact the extension author for bug reports.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using vertical workspaces for many years, and it was something that was missing when I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I believe I have found a complete solution to build vertical workspaces on Ubuntu 22.04, which requires using the following:

1. Gnome Shell Extension
2. Workspace Switcher Manager
3. DConf Editor

Here are the steps to install and configure this feature.

## 1 - Gnome Shell Extension

The installation can be made from the command line:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

Then launch the Extension Manager:

```
extension-manager
```

## 2 - Workspace Switcher Manager

**To install this extension:**
Go to the Browse Tab of `extension-manager`, search for `Workspace Switcher Manager`, and click Install.
[image]

**To enable the vertical workspaces:**
Go to the Installed Tab of `extension-manager` and click on the gear icon next to the `Workspace Switcher Manager` extension.

Under `General Tab -> Workspaces` enable the `Reverse Workspace Orientation`.
[image]

Now, the vertical workspaces should be enabled, and the rest of the options like number of desktops, Fixed etc., can be configured from `Settings -> Multitasking`
[image]

However, this is not over yet, as it disables any customized keyboard Shortcuts for switching and navigation besides the system defaults. Therefore, needs also some small adjustments in `dconf-editor`

## 3 - DConf-Editor

The editor can be installed by using the following command:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then start the editor:

```
dconf-editor
```

Navigate to `org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> keybindings` and change the settings for `switch-to-workspace-down` and `switch-to-workspace-up` as desired.
[image]

Alternatively, this can be done even from a terminal by using `gsettings`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down <key-bind>
```