# Can you change the 22.04 UI to look like 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, gui, appearance

I upgraded to 22.04 recently and I don't really like the new UI

Is there a way to get the UI of 20.04 or atleast look somewhat similar, while keeping 22.04 features?

For example:

**The overview** (If that's what it's called)

[image]

I miss the vertical overview and how each desktop workspace took up the entire screen
[image]

This is the main thing for now, other features I can't remember off the top of my head, but others feel free to comment down what else you would want back, so that the solution provided can include how to revert them back as well.

Comment: It may help to be more specific about what you don't like about 22.04 and what you do like about 20.04.

Comment: @mchid I edited the answer, can you take a look now?

Comment: @Someone I'm not experienced enough to make those modifications, could you perhaps post a solution to further elaborate what you mean?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 uses Gnome 4 (40) and 20.04 uses Gnome 3 (36). Gnome 3 is designed to show the workspaces vertically, on the contrary Gnome 40 is designed to show the workspaces horizontally. AFAIK it's because of the new gestures and shell design. There are some extensions such as vertical workspaces as mentioned in mchid's answer to revert this behaviour but it might cause the shell to misbehave. So it is not a good idea in my opinion. Speaking of the error you are facing while using the extension, https://github.com/RensAlthuis/vertical-overview/issues/92 it works after on and off.

Comment: @Someone Ubuntu 22.04 uses Gnome Shell 42. Version 40 was for 21.10.

Comment: @mchid oh I see, my bad, I haven't used 21.10 and above from a while. But still, does it change the facts (or rather opinions) stated above?

Comment: @cakelover Okay, it looks like [you need the Vertical Workspaces Gnome shell extension instead of Vertical Overlay](https://askubuntu.com/a/1419997/167115). I will delete this answer and mark your question as a duplicate if this works. You should probably disable the Vertical Overlay extension as this one seems to conflict with the Ubuntu Dock extension (I assume because the same exact issue exists with Dash to Dock and Dash to Panel which are similar).

Comment: @Someone Yeah, [I think it conflicts with the Ubuntu Dock](https://github.com/RensAlthuis/vertical-overview/issues/96) extension but I found an answer that uses the Vertical Workspaces extension instead of Vertical Overlays.

Comment: The Gnome Shell Extension page for [Vertical Workspaces can be found here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5177/vertical-workspaces/).

Comment: @Someone It looks like Vertical Workspaces is specifically made for Gnome Shell 40+.

Comment: @mchid Oh! I see. Vertical Workspaces seems to be a great work over. Although, still these extensions do not seem to fit properly on Gnome 40+. Let's see what happens.