# How to Make Workspaces Scroll Up and Down in 22.04.1

Tags: workspace-switcher

Workspaces by default scroll left and right in Ubuntu 22.04.1. I prefer the 20.04 way, up and down. Is there software I could use to change the direction of the scroll?

Thanks if anyone can figure this out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch back workspace movement to up/down instead of left/right on 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419991/switch-back-workspace-movement-to-up-down-instead-of-left-right-on-22-04)

Comment: yep that words thanks!